# How do I boot to a command line interface instead of a GUI?

Tags: gui

Hi I have ubuntu server 10.04 installed and I also installed the following:

```
su
aptitude install xorg xfce4
aptitude install <name of GUI browser, I use firefox>
aptitude install gedit
aptitude install gnome-terminal
```

Now when I restart the system it goes to the GUI login, what I am really after is a system that loads the CLI by default and then I can use startx to load the GUI when really necessary. I am trying to learn CLI but I would like to retain access to the GUI for now.
And, how can I switch between CLI and GUI anytime?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modify your file `/etc/default/grub` with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

and do `sudo update-grub`. The machine will boot in text mode.

To start the graphical interface you do

```
sudo service gdm start
```

**Edit**

Starting from Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric, the default Display Manager is LightDM, so the preceding command becomes:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Comment: this worked for me, except the command to start the GUI. Instead, I used this command: `startx`

Comment: Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"text"` has no effect for me on 14.04. Any clues?

Comment: the grub file doesn't exist with xubuntu via ubuntu arm 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the display manager, gdm (for Gnome)/kdm (for KDE)/etc, to not start on boot, or you can just remove the packages.

To prevent the display manager from starting, run:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f remove gdm   #For Gnome
sudo update-rc.d -f remove kdm   #For KDE
```

or, to remove the display manager:

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm           #For Gnome
sudo apt-get purge kdm           #For KDE
```

Comment: What does `sudo update-rc.d -f remove gdm` actually *do*? As well as out of curiosity, I'm asking because the command needs modification for Ubuntu 14.04: it doesn't work as it is. Replacing `gdm` with `lightdm` doesn't work, either.