# What packages do I remove to get a command line only mode?

Tags: command-line, text-mode

I was attempting to install a command line only version of Ubuntu and followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems#Install_an_Ubuntu_command-line_system).

I downloaded the alternate CD and went through the installation, but never got an "Install a command-line system." option.

12.04 is now up and running, though I don't need the desktop GUI. From what I have [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52089/how-do-i-boot-to-a-command-line-interface-instead-of-a-gui) I can set it back into text mode using grub, but what packages should I remove that I don't need any more?

Comment: If you want to install a command-line only version of Ubuntu, I would recommend installing Ubuntu Server. By default, it doesn't install any server packages like Apache, it asks you during installation.

Comment: That was my first thought, but then I read about installing the desktop version with `command-line-only` option and thought that was the way to go.

Comment: I've never heard of that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I'm not sure why the answer about the grub setting that you've linked to is marked as correct, it shouldn't work.</s> [This other answer <s>is the correct one.</s>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73922/grub-cmdline-linux-default-text-is-not-working) shows a configuration that will stop upstart from even trying to start lightdm. Adding `text` to the boot cmdline will instead make lightdm's upstart script bail out early when upstart tries to launch it.

The package for the Ubuntu desktop GUI is appropriately named `ubuntu-desktop`. Remove this and all dependencies of it that you don't explicitly need anymore if disk space is an issue. But if disk space is not a problem, you could just leave them installed, because they won't use any other resources as long as they're not actually used.

Comment: I can confirm the grub setting (http://askubuntu.com/questions/52089/how-do-i-boot-to-a-command-line-interface-instead-of-a-gui) does indeed work. I think i will just leave them on there for now, it was just annoying having to install them all in the first place.

Comment: Right, I understand that grub setting now. It was very hard to find out how it works exactly, though. It's in the lightdm upstart script `/etc/init/lightdm.com` where this setting is actually handled. I will edit my answer accordingly.