# How do I use a text-only interface to log in?

Tags: command-line, 12.10, login, gui, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I boot to a command line interface instead of a GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52089/how-do-i-boot-to-a-command-line-interface-instead-of-a-gui)

I am running Ubuntu 12.10. When my computer boots, I want to log into my computer only using the CLI, not the default GUI given by ubuntu, and use the CLI to choose a window manager after I log in. I am aware of Ctrl+Alt+F*, but that is one more keypress - unless I can default to one of those.

How would I go about disabling the GUI login, and playing with the CLI log in instead?

Comment: If I have understood your question properly, is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52089/how-do-i-boot-to-a-command-line-interface-instead-of-a-gui?rq=1) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your file `/etc/default/grub` with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

and do `sudo update-grub`. The machine will boot in text mode.

To start the graphical interface you do

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

**Courtesy:** https://askubuntu.com/a/52117/11932 and modified for Ubuntu 12.10.